# Error al conectarme a una base de datos en visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio

buenas tardes
Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos en visual studio 2019 que previamente he creado en Microsoft SQL Server, pero me da un error al abrir la base de datos. El error me da en la línea de Conexion.Open y es el siguiente:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)'.

Win32Exception: El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.

Este es el código de mi ventana para abrir la conexión.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CompraVentaConConexion
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para VentanaClientes.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class VentanaClientes : Window
{
    SqlConnection conexion;

    public VentanaClientes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String cadenaDeConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CompraVentaConConexion.Properties.Settings.Compra_VentaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaDeConexion);
    }

    private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string consultaSql = "INSERT INTO CLIENTES(idC, nomC) VALUES(@v_idC, @v_nomC)";
        conexion.Open();

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consultaSql, conexion);

        SqlParameter paramIdC = new SqlParameter("@v_idC", tbCodigoCliente.Text);
        SqlParameter paramNomC = new SqlParameter("@v_nomC", tbNombreCliente.Text);

        comando.Parameters.Add(paramIdC);
        comando.Parameters.Add(paramNomC);

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conexion.Close();

    }

    private void btnVolver_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VentanaOpciones vo = new VentanaOpciones();
        vo.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Este es el código del archivo de configuración (App.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CompraVentaConConexion.Properties.Settings.Compra_VentaConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-1RV7APRC;Initial Catalog=Compra_Venta;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=case"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te diría que utilices dapper, ya que se reduce mucho el código y mantienes la flexibilidad de las consultas en querys. Te dejo las posibles dos soluciones ante tu código.

```
    Cualquier duda hazmelo saber, un saludo
    
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Dapper;
    
    
    namespace CompraVentaConConexion
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Lógica de interacción para VentanaClientes.xaml
        /// </summary>
    public partial class VentanaClientes : Window
    {


        string cadenaDeConexion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompraVentaConConexion.Properties.Settings.Compra_VentaConnectionString"];
    
        public VentanaClientes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
    
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaDeConexion))
            {
                //Forma1
                string consultaSql = "INSERT INTO CLIENTES(idC, nomC) VALUES(@v_idC, @v_nomC)";
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consultaSql, conexion);
    
                SqlParameter paramIdC = new SqlParameter("@v_idC", tbCodigoCliente.Text);
                SqlParameter paramNomC = new SqlParameter("@v_nomC", tbNombreCliente.Text);
    
                comando.Parameters.Add(paramIdC);
                comando.Parameters.Add(paramNomC);
    
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    
                //Forma 2 (Usando dapper)
                connection.Execute(consultaSql, new { v_idC = tbCodigoCliente.Text, v_nomC = tbNombreCliente.Text });
    
            }
    
    
            
           
    
        }
    
        private void btnVolver_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VentanaOpciones vo = new VentanaOpciones();
            vo.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si te vuelve a dar problemas de conexión simplemente reinicia la instancia de sql server que tienes corriendo en tu pc. Quizá eso también podría ser lo que te está dando problemas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas graciás por la sugerencia